# Describe an algorithm that checks if edge e is in MST of G

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have an exercise in algorithms with this question: G is connected weighted graph, and I need to describe a linear time algorithm that checks if there exists a minimum spanning Tree that contains the edge e.

let edge e=(u,v), so I thought about starting building an MST from u and check if edge e is safe to add to the MST (for example by using prim algorithm). and doing the same starting from v. Will it work?

Comment: How fast should this algorithm be?

Comment: edited, thank you.

Comment: Linear to what? Edges or vertices?

Comment: not specified in the exercise, could be O(|V|+|E|)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317312/how-to-check-if-edge-is-in-some-mst-linear-time/317364#317364

Comment: I saw that, but I'm asking if my algorithm will work as well